# Optimising SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I have a SQL query that performs an INNER JOIN on two tables having >50M rows each. I wish to reduce the time it takes to search through the join by reducing the rows that are joined based on a column present on one of the tables.

Say I have table1 with columns A,B,C and table2 with columns A,D,E. I wish to join based on column A but only those rows that have value 'e' for column E of table 2.

My SQL query :

```
SELECT one.B, two.D
FROM table1 one
INNER JOIN table2 two WHERE two.E IN ('e')
ON one.A = two.A
WHERE one.B > 10
AND two.D IN ('...')
```

It gives the error :

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Where am I going wrong? How do I achieve the intended result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT one.B, two.D
FROM table1 one
INNER JOIN table2 two -- WHERE two.E IN ('e')  --> shouldn't use where here
ON one.A = two.A and two.E = 'e'
WHERE one.B > 10
AND two.D IN ('...')
```

Comments included in the code.

Comment: Perhaps make the `AND two.E = 'e'` as well, since you're not actually asking the DB to evaluate a tuple.  Chances are the query optimizer knows that though.

Answer (score 0):

You could also put the condition in the Where clause

```
SELECT one.B, two.D
FROM table1 a
   JOIN table2 b
       ON b.A = a.A 
WHERE a.B > 10
   And b.E = 'e'
   AND b.D In ('...')
```

EDITED to remove 2nd incorrect suggestion

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you decide that IN is subject to performance issues? I've never come across such in my experience - esp. since Oracle will convert an IN-list into OR predicates behind the scenes.

Comment: You know, it's based only on my subjective experience - but research online because of your comment indicates that I am wrong... I am deleting that part of my answer. Thanks.

Comment: ok; maybe you had confused it with some other performance issue (if your brain is anything like mine!), or maybe you came across a bug affecting a particular scenario at some point in time? *{:-)

Answer (score 0):

As vkp pointed out, the WHERE is improperly used. Instead you could also make a subquery to include that where statement. So that:

```
INNER JOIN table2 two WHERE two.E IN ('e')
```

becomes

```
INNER JOIN (select * from table2 WHERE E IN ('e')) two
```